# Display Previous Days sales excluding Weekends In PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I'm having trouble creating a measure that will display the total sales of the previous day minus weekends. The goal is if its a Monday that visual would show sales data for the previous Friday. If it's a Saturday or Sunday it still displays Friday.

I have already created a rolling calendar in PowerBI and adding a calculated column to that lists a 1 and 0 for it the date is a weekend or weekday.

The measure I have written display the previous day but I can't figure out how to filter so the previous day shown never is a weekend:

```
PreviousDaysSamples = CALCULATE([Total Samples], PREVIOUSDAY(Dates[Date.1]))
```

Any help would be great. I've looked and just haven't been able to find any solution yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add in an IF condition.

For example, the below will check if the day of the week is a Monday (DAYOFWEEK = 1) and then use Fridays data DATEADD(Dates[Date.1], -2, day), else use the previous day for all other days. You would need to add in a few more conditions to cater for the Saturday and Sundays to get back to the Friday, but this example should put you on the right track.

```
PreviousDaysSamples = IF (DAYOFWEEK(Dates[Date.1] = 1), 
CALCULATE([Total Samples], DATEADD(Dates[Date.1], -2, day)),  
CALCULATE([Total Samples], PREVIOUSDAY(Dates[Date.1])))
```

There are some additional techniques [listed here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Last-weekday-Dax-formula/td-p/24818)

Comment: I made some progress with the following: YesterdaySamples = CALCULATE([Total Samples], FILTER(Dates,PREVIOUSDAY(DSS_DATA[Run_Date])))

The problem I am running into is when I add a date slider and the date range changes from the current month it seems to calculate all sales within the date range.

Comment: That is the expected behaviour of a slider. What visual are you using to display your data? The calculation you have in your comment will not skip the weekend days. I have added a link to a post I found - which seems to do what you want.